# MS Access / SQL : Invalid Use of Property

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

The code below is supposed to insert a new record into the transactions table. However, it results in a compile erro "Invalid Use of Property" on the SET QDF line. What could cause such an error?

```
Private Sub cmdCharge_Click()
Dim vblMealType As String
Dim vblMealQual As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database


If txtMealID.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then

        MsgBox "Please Select a Meal Type", _
               vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Else



 MsgBox "Customer Charge Succesfull.", _
              vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Dim QDF As DAO.QueryDef
QDF = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS prmCustomerID Text(255), prmMealID Text(255), prmTransactionAmount Currency, prmTransactionDate Text(255);" & _
        "INSERT INTO dbo_Transactions (CustomerID, MealID, TransactionAmount, TransactionDate) " & _
        "VALUES ([prmCustomerID], [prmMealID], [prmTransactionAmount], [prmTransactionDate])")


QDF!prmCustomerID = txtCustomerID.Value
QDF!prmMealID = txtMealID.Value
QDF!prmTransactionAmount = txtCharge.Value
QDF!prmTransactionDate = Date
QDF.Execute dbFailOnError
 MsgBox "Customer Charge Succesfull.", _
              vbOKOnly + vbInformation

Set QDF = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

DoCmd.OpenForm "Charge Form"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `QDF` is an object variable, you must use the `Set` keyword when you assign a value to it.

```vb
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Dim QDF As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "PARAMETERS prmCustomerID Text(255), prmMealID Text(255), prmTransactionAmount Currency, prmTransactionDate Text(255);" & _
        "INSERT INTO dbo_Transactions (CustomerID, MealID, TransactionAmount, TransactionDate) " & _
        "VALUES ([prmCustomerID], [prmMealID], [prmTransactionAmount], [prmTransactionDate])"
Debug.Print strInsert 
Set QDF = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", strInsert)
```